# Pedagogic reference on cut generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomial-time, integer-programming, mathematical-programming

Can you recommend an introduction to the topic of cut generating functions?  I am looking for introductory or review-like material.

I did find the following survey paper, but it seems to be addressed to experts, so not what I'm looking for:

[A geometric approach to cut-generating functions](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~abasu9/papers/final-ISMP-survey.pdf).  Amitabh Basu, Michele Conforti, Marco Di Summa.

I have talked to a few researchers in the topic and haven't been able to find anything good.  I do not have access to libraries at this point and can't access books, so I would prefer freely available online resources.

Comment: 1. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the specific paper you happen to be reading right now.  Is there a specific topic you are looking for information on?  2. What research/self-study have you done?  Have you spent some time at a library or with Google to find relevant textbooks?  3. Note that requests for a collection of links are rarely a good fit for our site's format.  We don't want to be just a link farm.

Comment: I am looking for introductory/pedagogic references on cut generating functions.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include all relevant information in the body of the question: comments exist only to help you improve your post, and readers shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  And you still haven't addressed my comments 2 or 3.

Comment: I find the next questions a bit offensive in the sense that you are presuming that as if I haven't spent effort on this already. Ofcourse I have and I haven't been able to find anything good! I have talked to a few researchers in the topic too. (...it does remain that I don't have access to libraries at this point and hence I can't access books..)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you found it offensive.  I'm not presuming anything.  If you haven't told us what research you've done, how would we know?  Part of the premise of this site's format is that we expect you to try standard resources before asking, and share in the question what you've tried, for multiple reasons: (1) so that answerers don't duplicate your effort or tell you something you already know, (2) to help you clarify what will/won't meet your needs, (3) but also in the spirit of "knowledge sharing", to help others who might have the same issue.

Comment: @D.W.  I would appreciate it if someone could explain (or give a reference that does) the motivation behind these cut generating functions starting with nothing more than the definition of a cutting plane /chvatal cuts;  why should we care about the geometry of cut generating functions?